# Modifying UISearchBar Cancel button font text color and style

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Is there any way to change the text font and color of the UISearchBar Cancel button without subclassing the searchbar?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can change Cancel button styling by changing the appearance of `UIBarButtonItem` when contained in `UISearchBar`.

For example,

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIColor blueColor], 
                                                      UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                                      [UIColor darkGrayColor], 
                                                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                                      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
                                                      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                      nil] 
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This is the best answer on this topic I can find anywhere.

Comment: Those who just wants to set custom UISearchBar cacel button color use tintColor       [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: To just set the font style & size, I used something like this: `[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:14]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I set this in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.  I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 with iOS 7 SDK and running on an iOS 6.1 simulator.  The cancel button stays the same color.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

### Swift 3

```
let attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 5**

```
let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Comment: For **Swift 5** replace `NSAttributedStringKey` with `NSAttributedString.Key`

Comment: this save my day

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to modify **Cancel** button, you can do it by:

```
if let cancelButton = searchBar.valueForKey("cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    cancelButton.setTitle(<your_string>, forState: <UIControlState>)
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(<your_uicolor>, forState: <UIControlState>)
    cancelButton.setAttributedTitle(<your_nsattributedstring>, forState: <UIControlState>)
}
```

where `searchBar` is your `UISearchBar` object.

Comment: This is the best answer if you don't want *all* of the `UIBarButtonItem`s in the `UISearchBar`s of your app to be customized the same way

Answer (score 6):

Based on htinlinn's answer, this is what I used in my `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller using the search bar in iOS 7:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
                     setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] 
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplified Swift version of @htinlinn answer:

```
let attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.textBlueColor,
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
]
UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

For modifying the search bar cancel button you have take Button object and change the reference of that button to your custom button.

> ```
> UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,300,30)];
> searchBar.delegate = self;
> searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
> searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
> UIButton *cancelButton;
> for (id button in searchBar.subviews)
> {
>     if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
>    {
>         cancelButton=(UIButton*)button;
>         break;
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tint property of searchBar to change the color of searchBar, cancel button's color will get changed but according to the color of UISearchBar. I can't be edited manually. But you can always put a custom over it in the interface builder which will hide the native cancel button. And the user will use your custom button as the cancel button of the searchBar.

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution after iOS 9.0 (by modifying htinlinn's answer):

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.classForCoder()])
        .setTitleTextAttributes([
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor(),
            NSShadowAttributeName: NSShadow(color: UIColor.redColor(), offset: CGSizeMake(0, -1), blurRadius: 2)
            ],
            forState: UIControlState.Normal)
} else {
    // Link to Objective-C Method
}
```

And the current Objective-C method (`UITextAttributeTextColor` is deprecated since iOS 7.0):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
                          NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]}
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

My little shadow extension used in the code above:

```
extension NSShadow {
    convenience init(color: AnyObject!, offset: CGSize, blurRadius: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
        self.shadowColor = color
        self.shadowOffset = offset
        self.shadowBlurRadius = blurRadius
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSShadow' with an argument list of type '(color: UIColor, offset: CGSize, blurRadius: Int)'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my little extension. I updated my answer with the code.

Comment: Side note: you could use ```UISearchBar.self``` instead of ```UISearchBar.classForCoder()```

Answer (score -1):

A much better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936413/2099097)

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_cancelButton"];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor yourColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Your Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and similarly you can change other style and text properties of the button.

For iOS 13.* (@AnujAroshA answer in comments)

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [searchBar valueForKey:@"cancelButton"];
```

Comment: You may find an error since in iOS 13 & upper since key has been changed from `_cancelButton` to `cancelButton`. Means they have dropped the underscore character from the key.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:14]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```