# How to customise the UISearchBar cancel button

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a
`@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!`
and I'm trying to change the font and color of the `cancel` button with but it's not working. The code I'm using is the following:

```
fileprivate static func applyStyle() {
            let appearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
            let commonAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: UIFont.bodySmall,
                .foregroundColor: ColorEnum.black,
                .kern: NSNumber(value: Float(NLLetterSpacing.bodySmall))
            ]
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(commonAttributes, for: .normal)
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(commonAttributes, for: .highlighted)
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([
                .font: UIFont.bodySmall,
                .foregroundColor: ColorEnum.pinkishGrey,
                .kern: NSNumber(value: Float(NLLetterSpacing.bodySmall))
            ], for: .disabled)
        }
```

However, I also have a `weak var searchController: UISearchController?` and the code it's working for it's `searchController.searchBar`.

Comment: from SO I found that `UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)` should be used, but I don't see that in your code.

Link: [Modifying UISearchBar Cancel button font text color and style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329454/11332605)
Tested the answer and it is working for me

Comment: adding `UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(commonAttributes, for: .normal)` should do the trick, then you could easily get rid of the appearance

Comment: @Jokecoder can u add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(commonAttributes, for: .normal)
```

should do the trick, then you could easily get rid of the appearance