# Image for Cancel button of UISearchbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiimage, uisearchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Styling the cancel button in a UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200149/styling-the-cancel-button-in-a-uisearchbar)

I am trying to set image for searchbar, I can set image for searchabar using searchbar's subview `UISearchBarBackground`, but I am not able to set image for cancel button of searchbar. I get searchbar subview `UINavigationButton` for button but I dnt knowhow to set image on `UINavigationButton`. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling the cancel button in a UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200149/styling-the-cancel-button-in-a-uisearchbar) and this [How do I change the UISearchbar cancel button's text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992917/how-do-i-change-the-uisearchbar-cancel-buttons-text-color)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this code...

```
    for (UIView *searchbuttons in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([searchbuttons isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)searchbuttons;
            cancelButton.enabled = YES;
            [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
    }
```