# Change Keyboard Color in UISearchBar with apperance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I want to change the color of the keyboard to black, when the user taps on the search textfield.

I was trying to achieve it with
`UITextField *textField = [UITextField appearance];
    [textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];`

but my build fails with this message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISearchBarTextField _UIAppearance_setKeyboardAppearance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8485260'

Please can you help me with that?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code...

```
    for(UIView *searchTextfield in yourSearchBar.subviews)
    {
        if([searchTextfield isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]){
            [(UITextField *)searchTextfield setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        }
    }
```

its same like my another answer in which i replace the button Image see.. [image-for-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019719/image-for-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar/14019754#14019754)

Answer (score 1):

Upvote to Paras Joshi's answer, and an update for iOS7/8. The UIView is now wrapped in one more layer, so you'll want to iterate once more.

```
 for(UIView *searchTextfield in self.searchBar.subviews)
    {
        for(UIView *searchTextfield2 in searchTextfield.subviews) {
            if([searchTextfield2 isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]){
                [(UITextField *)searchTextfield2 setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
            }
        }


    }
```

Standard disclaimer. This is "officially" frowned upon by Apple, but because you're simply iterating through UIViews using public api, you're "technically" okay.