# Change UISearchBar Cancel button to icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uisearchcontroller

I want to change the `UISearchBar`'s `Cancel` button to one that only has an image, and no text. Here's where I got to so far from original behaviour

[image]

to this

[image]

A step in the right direction, but the problem is the button is too wide. When I debug the view, I can see that it has button label insets of 11 points on left and right. **Does anyone know how to make the button fit the content size?** The image is square.

Here's my code for customising the button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar;

if (IOS9) {
    barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]];
} else {
    barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
}

barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Close"];
barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar.title = nil;
```

Another weird issue is that when I dismiss the search bar and activate it again, the button image turns dark (it's still there, I can see it when debugging the views), so it looks like this

[image]

**Any idea how to keep the icon white?** I tried this method below, but without results:

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image for Cancel button of UISearchbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019719/image-for-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar)

Comment: Thanks, I've read that question before, but the problem here is different. I know how to change the background color of this button IF I want to keep it as a text button, but I don't - I want it to be just the image. Can you please unmark it as a possible duplicate?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the wide space problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use image rendering and tint color.

```
barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Close"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar.title = nil;
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. This did solve my second issue, only I had to use the rendering mode `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Swift 4.1 Version of @jamesBlake 's answer:

```
 func setUpSearchBar() {

    let barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar: UIBarButtonItem?
    barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
    barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar?.image = UIImage(named: "Home.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar?.tintColor = UIColor.white
    barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar?.title = nil
}
```