# Unable to change UISearchBar cancel button title color after changing it's text.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uisearchbar

I'm using this code to change UISearchBar cancel button title:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
UIView* view=_otsinguRiba.subviews[0];
for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;

        if (cancelButton) {
        [cancelButton setTitle:@"Test") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
}
```

While changing the text works fine, changing the color doesn't. It stays black.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer to this on SO a while back, but I don't recall where. Here's the code that I'm using to set the color of the text.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [UIColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                //[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                //[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                nil]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: That works indeed. But in what method do you usually use this code? Already in `- (void)viewDidLoad`?

Comment: This is a global setting that will apply to all UISearchBar elements within your app. I typically set those in the app delegate class, in the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, so the settings will be applied before any view controllers are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the iOS Runtime Property `_cancelButton` to achieve this.

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_cancelButton"];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor yourColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```